# Callback on library android

Tags: android, service, interface, callback

i'm trying to use event bus to notify events from my library to a service.
Up until now i've been using EventBus like this:

```
public abstract class MLibraryClass{

....
EventBus.getDefault().post(event);
...
```

}

```
public class MService{
...
public void onEvent(Event event){
 //do stuff
}
```

}

and now i've created an interface in order to use the callback. Problem is the callback has a null reference and i don't know how to instance it.

interface:

```
public Interface MInterface{
    void doStuff(Event event);
}
```

Library class:

```
public abstract class MLibraryClass{
...
MInterface interface;
Event event;
...
public void onEvent(){
    interface.doStuff(event)
}
...
```

}

service:

```
public class MService implements MInterface{
...
void doStuff(Event event){
    //some code
}
...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a method in your `MLibraryClass` like below and do something like this :

```
public abstract class MLibraryClass{
...
MInterface interface;
Event event;
...
public void onEvent(){
    if(interface!=null) interface.doStuff(event)
}

public void setInterace(MyInterface myInterface){
    this.interface = myInterface;
}
...
```

Android from the place you are accessing MLibraryClass, set the interface.